# probleme with gdm

Tags: gdm, init.d

I have a problem with gdm , when I run this command

sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start

I got this message

```
/etc/init.d/gdm: 79: /etc/init.d/gdm: syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

So, can anyone help me please

Comment: You will need to file a bug report. We may be able to give you a fix if you update your question and post the contents of `/etc/init.d/gdm`

Comment: It is bug in gdm. See [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1315442).

Comment: How can i do that sorry but i am new ubuntu user

Comment: use ubuntu pastebin and post the link back. +1 to finding some of the restrictions for new users frustrating at times.

Comment: how can i find the contents of /etc/init.d/gdm

Comment: use `cat /etc/init.d/gdm` or use `gedit /etc/init.d/gdm`, copy and past on http://pastebin.com/

Comment: it does not want to copy i am using putty what i am gonna do ?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8429162/ this is it so what you think ?

Answer (score 3):

There is an extra `fi` at line 79 as reported in [Extra "fi" in /etc/init.d/gdm](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm/+bug/1315442) bug (see g_p comment).

To fix it open `/etc/init.d/gdm` with your favorite editor (for example: `sudo vi /etc/init.d/gdm`), go to line 79 (`:79<return>`), remove this line (`dd`) and save file (`:wq`).

Than use this command to start service:

```
sudo service gdm start
```

and this should works.